How do I verify downloaded Ubuntu iso image?
Ok so I've downloaded the Ubuntu ISO from the Ubuntu website but I'm supposed to verify the download, right? So how do I do that exactly?

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

@muru My method here is the simplest and easiest way to verify your Ubuntu download.

You're welcome to post it in the duplicate.

@guiverc Yeah those instructions are very confusing. I'm a newbie and I tried to follow those instructions and I wanted to pull my hair out.

@muru If it's a duplicate will it still show up in the Google search results?

I generally use the sha256sum check which is mentioned in the duplicate link OR in the answer below. The answer [below] uses a 24.04 ISO, where as the duplicate uses an 18.10 ISO (but answer was written late 2018 thus 18.10 was the latest) if I didn't just download the ISO using zsync (that does a check at the end of the download)
